# IF na Funcão de resposta POST não funciona

Tags: php, javascript, post, if

tenho um POST dentro de uma função javascript e esse post retorna uma função resposta o problema e que o IF na função resposta não está funcionando

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mlogin" ).click(function() {
        $("#modallogin").modal({                    // wire up the actual modal functionality and show the dialog
                "backdrop"  : "static",
                "keyboard"  : false,
                "show"      : true                     // ensure the modal is shown immediately
        });
    });
    $("#btncancel" ).click(function() {
        $("#modallogin").modal("hide");
        $("#msg_login").html("");
    });
    $("#btnok" ).click(function() {
        var usuario = $('#usuario').val();
        var senha = $('#senha').val();
        var acao= "login";
        var startaction=1;
        $.post('controllers/clogin.php', {usuario:usuario , senha:senha, acao:acao, startaction:startaction}, function(resposta) {//enviamos o parametro nome, com o valor da variavel nome criada acima
                    //location.reload();
        $('#usuario').val(""), $('#senha').val(""), acao="", startaction=0;
            $("#msg_login").html(resposta);
            // O if abaixo não está funcionando
            if (resposta=="Você foi logado com sucesso"){
                $("#modallogin").modal("hide");
                $("#msg_login").html("");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Não está funcionando ou não está sendo executado? Já verificou se o valor em `resposta` é _exatamente_ "Você foi logado com sucesso"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que existam 3 possibilidades:

**1 -** a função `function(resposta){}` do seu código representa o parâmetro `success` da função `$.post;`

Isso significa que ele somente executa caso a função tenha sucesso, ou seja, o terceiro parâmetro da função, objecto `jqXHR`, tem os seguintes valores: `jqXHR.readyState = 4 e jqXHR.status = 200;`

Valores do readyState: 
0: request not initialized  
1: server connection established 
2: request received  
3: processing request  
4: request finished and response is ready

Valores do status (alguns) 
200: OK 
404: Page not found

Para ilustrar:

```
function(resposta, StringSucesso, retorno){
     console.log(retorno.status);
     console.log(retorno.readyState);
}
```

Caso ele não tenha terminado a requisição ou a resposta não estiver pronta, ele nao retorna 4 no `readyState`, caso ele não encontre a pagina requisitada ou outro problema externo ocorra ele não retorna 200 no status.

Dessa forma a função `success` não é executada.

**2 -** A função quebra ou encerra antes do `if`: caso exista um retorno o código seguinte ao retorno não será executado. Caso ocorra um erro do `javascript` antes do `if`, o código seguinte também não executa.

**3 -** `resposta=="Você foi logado com sucesso"`, a analise da resposta não tem nenhum tratamento, ou seja, você está lendo o retorno como texto pleno.

Não é uma boa prática, e digo que é uma péssima prática principalmente para nós que falamos português, já que nossa linguagem tem acentuação.

Como você usa `PHP` para o `webservice` e `AJAX` para requisição eu sugiro o uso de `JSON`:

Preparando o código a ser retornado pelo `PHP`:

```
 $array = Array();
 $array['sucesso'] = 1 // valor varia 1 ou 0, 1 para sucesso e 0 para erro
 $array['mensagem'] = "Você foi logado com sucesso" // A mensagem retornada pelo webservice
 echo json_encode($array);
```

A função `json_encode`, transforma o array em texto `json`, além de codificar acentuação e outros caracteres.

Preparando a leitura do retorno no `Javascript`:

```
try{
      var objResponse = JSON.parse(response);

      if(objResponse.sucesso == 1){
    // Executa o código de sucesso
        console.log(objResponse.mensagem);
      }else{
    // Executa o código de erro (negação)
        console.log(objResponse.mensagem);
      }


}catch(e){
    // Faz o tratamento da exceção (e);
}
```

Espero te-lo ajudado.